# Crashlytics: View all Sessions does not display all custom keys

Tags: android, crashlytics

I have an Android app that uses Crashlytics for crash reporting.
I am already using the setString function to included some data in the report for each user that logs in to my app

```
Crashlytics.setString(key, value)
```

From my dashboard, theres a crash and it shows that there are multiple users that experienced this crash

[image]
But when I View All Sessions, it will only display 1 set of data:

[image]

Shouldnt be displaying 6 sets of these data??
Im sure diff users have diff data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, there are arrows next to the date that let you to check another session like below:

[image: example]

Each one will have it's own set of keys that you can view.